# Regular expression to get substring of a match

Tags: regex

Sorry for the odd wording, I'm not sure how to describe what I need to do succinctly...

I need to extract the first part of a part number from a string returned from our systems database.  The part numbers have generally the following format:

```
VENDOR FIRST123-SECOND123
```

`VENDOR` is optional, as is the separating hyphen. I need to end up with `FIRST123`, or the last whole "word" if there is no hyphen.

So far I can get the `FIRST123-SECOND123` with the following:

```
[^ ]*$
```

I have not been able to figure out how to split the resulting match to get everything prior to any hyphen character.  Ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I bet there could be a stack-exchange solely devoted to regular expressions.

Comment: Hint: restructure your database ;-)

Comment: This is a free-form text entry field for entering a description of the part.  Good luck restructuring that!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/[^-\s]+(?=\S*$)/
```

This captures the first sequence of non-hyphen, non-whitespace characters that is separated from the end only by non-whitespaces.

Yet, I'd say string methods would be of much more help. Get the `lastIndexOf(" ")`, and from there the `firstIndexOf("-")`, and then get the substring between these.

Comment: This doesn't work... However, after looking at some of the possible entries (see my "free-form text" comment above) I think I am much better off using string function.  I'll give you the answer for that suggestion  :)

Comment: Hm, worksforme (with your input example). What language do you use, which match options did you set?

Comment: I use Expresso to build / test my regular expressions, with default parameters. If I leave the leading and trailing slash characters I get no match.  If I remove them I get both FIRST123 and SECOND123 as matches.

Comment: Yes, the slashes are only common regex-literal delimiters, depending on your language of choice you need other characters (or write the regex in a string literal). To get only one result, use a "matchFirst" method or kind of, and/or drop the "global" flag.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I worked with regexes a lot a few years back, but now I don't use them often enough to be fluent anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my regular expression to get what you want:

```
[^ ]*\w*(?=-)
```

You started off well. `\w*` says "get all word characters" (letters and numbers) and `(?=-)` says "up to one that is followed by a dash"

Comment: What is the `[^ ]*` good for? I fear, together with `\w*` this could even lead to catastrophic backtracking if no dash is found.

Comment: The [^ ]* is to skip any leading space-delimited words.  This doesn't work for me either, not because the regex doesn't work but due to the unstructured nature of my source text.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Might as well throw my suggestion in there. Asserts that there is no more text after the second part number.

`/[a-zA-z]\+\d\+[^$]`